Improving write performance for 100 million writes daily on Postgres
We have posgres 15 in RDS and the instance is db.m6g.4xlarge with 64Gb RAM.
We want to write to a table that is date partitioned and has two UUID fields (lets call them id1, id2) and few other attributes which are mostly integer.
The unique contraint on this table is defined as

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_1 ON ONLY public.my_table USING btree (id1,
date, id2) INCLUDE (processed_at)
where processed_at is a datatime attribute.

We have to insert around 100 million data on this table daily and if there is a conflict, we upsert based on the latest processed_at, basically upsert only when processed_at from upstream > processed_at in db.
We take around 8hours to compeletly process this data (we read it from kafka and insert it into db and nothing else in java layer). we want to improve its write speed.
We tried tuning the following RDS parameters

shared_buffer -> changed to 25 gb or 40% of RAM
checkpoint_timeour -> increased from 5 min to 15 min
max_wal_size -> set to 50Gb

However there is not much improvement and one thing that i noted is that around 80% of the time is spend on IO:DataFileRead which essentially means data not found in buffer so a IO is performed to read from the disk.
Need to understand

Why so much Time is spend on IO:DataFileRead
How to improve the writes (we are doing a batch write of 2000 per batch)

Update :
Adding few more detaILS

The given unique constraint is the only index present in the table.
Each partition is around 3.5 to 4Gb (a partition for each day) and the index size is around 1.3Gb
The disk type is  db.m6g.4xlarge with 64Gb RAM. EBS-only, with Dedicated EBS Bandwidth (Mbps) of 4750 and Network Performance up to 10 Gbps


Is there a reason your unique index is the order (id1, date, id2)? This means that lookups in the index to add new rows will be effectively random, and thus unless the full index is in memory its going to involve hitting disk often. It might help to change the order to (date, id1, id2), if your inserts are clustered by date at all.

My data is date partitioned and every date is a new partition, and we achieve this by pg_partman. Can you explain why the current order of id1, date, id2 will hit more disk then data, id1, id2?

We'd need to see the queries at fault and their execution plans. In a hosted database, it could also be that you have lame disks.

If every new date is a new partition, then maybe that won't help you. But at that point the index is going to have effectively random access so I can't suggest anything other than get enough shared buffer to ensure you can fit a days index in RAM.

We have allocated 40% of RAM to shared buffer (25Gb). I did not see any improvements. Also even if day is first in the ordering then also it would have to do a random access on other two ids (id1, id2), isn't it?

@LaurenzAlbe the disk are high performing SSD

Yes, but Amazon with throttle the throughput. Anyway, without actual statements and execution plans, there is little we can do.

If date were the first column, then the access would only be random within the part of the index corresponding to that date, which (if not for the partitioning) would presumably much smaller than the index at large.  But if each date is its own partition, this shouldn't matter.  But in that case, is there any point in having date in the index at all?  It makes the index larger (and so harder to cache), but does it accomplish anything that can't be done without it?

Every row inserted needs to look up the tuple in the index to see if it is a duplicate. Unless your rows are inserted in order of id1, this basically means reading a random index leaf page for every tuple inserted, and then possibly reading a random table page as well. So I'm not surprised that this generates a lot of IO:DataFileRead if those pages are frequently misses.
If this is what is going on, you should find the performance starts out fast when it starts processing data into a new partition, but then falls off a cliff once the active-partition index size (or the sum of the index and table size, depending on how often the table is consulted) exceeds the size of the cache.  You have told us how much RAM you have, but haven't told us how large the index of each partition ends up being once it is fully populated.  Or for that matter, if there are other indexes than the unique one.
Your setting of shared_buffers to 40% of RAM is almost exactly wrong.  Since PostgreSQL does not (yet) use direct IO, every page read is first read into the filesystem cache (probably evicting a page from that cache) and then read into shared_buffers (probably also evicting a page from shared_buffers).  This results in most of the pages being in RAM twice, which means that many fewer buffers fit in RAM.  To minimize the double-buffering you would want to set shared_buffers to a small fraction of RAM so that the filesystem cache is the main cache, or a large fraction of RAM so that shared_buffers is the main cache.
If you were to sort each batch by id1 (and possibly use much larger batches) then you should hit the index in a more orderly fashion and it could be much more efficient.
You have said the disks are high performing SSD (but didn't give us the specifications). But generally to saturate the available IOPS of a high performance SSD you need to have many IO requests in flight at the same time. But in PostgreSQL an inserting job is only going to generate a single stream of IO read requests and won't proceed to the next request one until the current one is finished. A way around this is to arrange to have several jobs running at the same time inserting different tuples.
